# How to leave existing data unchanged is a condition is false

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, wpf

I am currently working on a project where I need to be able to rent a truck to a customer but also need to add the customer details if not existing. My problem is even though through the WPF form I input the exact same details of a customer, there would be a new set of data added thus creating a new Customer ID for one person. How would I be able to get the database disregard the existing customer details?

My data service code:

```
 public class DataService
{
    public static void rentTruck(TruckRental toRent, bool isNewCustomer)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DAD_TruckRental_RGMContext())
        {

            if (!isNewCustomer)
            {

                ctx.Entry(toRent.Customer).State = EntityState.Unchanged;//doesnt leave existing customer unchanged
            }
            ctx.Entry(toRent.Truck).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.TruckRental.Add(toRent);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

My cs code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            TruckCustomer cust = new TruckCustomer();
            cust.Age = int.Parse(ageTextBox.Text);
            cust.LicenseNumber = licenseNumberTextBox.Text;
            cust.LicenseExpiryDate = licenseExpiryDateDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date;


            TruckPerson per = new TruckPerson();
            per.Address = addressTextBox.Text;
            per.Telephone = telephoneTextBox.Text;
            per.Name = nameTextBox.Text;

            cust.Customer = per;


            int truckId = int.Parse(truckIdTextBox.Text);
            IndividualTruck truck = DataService.searchTruckByID(truckId);

            decimal priceTotal = decimal.Parse(totalPriceTextBox.Text);

            TruckRental toRent = new TruckRental();
            toRent.TotalPrice = priceTotal;
        toRent.RentDate = rentDateDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date;

        toRent.ReturnDueDate = returnDueDateDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
            toRent.Customer = cust;
            toRent.Truck = truck;
            truck.Status = "Rented";


            DataService.rentTruck(toRent, true);

            MessageBox.Show("Truck rented succesfully");


    }
```

Comment: That looks like a problem in the DataService.rentTruck method, not the code you have posted. Do you have access to that?

Comment: @RobinBennett yes its the code above

Comment: @GraceDelosReyes what is the unique key in customer table ?

Comment: @Saif CustomerID

Comment: @GraceDelosReyes do you key in CustomerId or auto generate ?

Comment: @Saif Its auto generated

Comment: @GraceDelosReyes you must have field to differentiate between users like email or name coz auto generated id will not differentiate

Comment: The database works differently depending if you have a primary key.  When a table has a primary key you can have only one row with the same key value.  If a table does not have a primary key then you can have multiple rows with the same value.  when a Primary key exists you have to use Update to change the value and Insert when putting a new key into the table.

Comment: @Saif I was thinking licenseNumber from the customer table but I am unsure on how to differentiate

Comment: What is 'DAD_TruckRental_RGMContext' ? Are you using EntityFramework?

Comment: @RobinBennett Yes I am using entity framework

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion

1- First check if customer details already exist in db using `LicenseNumber`
2- The first step will be either `null` or have details, so if null then add received customer details otherwise update

here is the code

```
public class DataService
{
    public static void rentTruck(TruckRental toRent, bool isNewCustomer, TruckCustomer tcustomer)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DAD_TruckRental_RGMContext())
        {
           var ob =  ctx.TruckCustomer.Where(c => c.LicenseNumber   == customer.LicenseNumber);
           if ( ob != null) //not exist 
            {

            //create new here 
            ctx.TruckCustomer.Add(tcustomer);
        }

        //exist then just update State
        ctx.ob.State = EntityState.Modified;
        ctx.AddOrUpdate(ob);
        ctx.TruckRental.Add(toRent);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I hope this can help you